# CcMiner monero mining GPU utilization

Tags: mining, gpu-mining, ccminer, monero-mining

I just started experimenting with Monero mining and got the setup pretty much done. I have a wallet and I'm successfully mining within a pool, using CcMiner. However, my GPU utilization hovers around 10% with few spikes now and then. Is this the normal behavior ? I always assumed that during mining my GPU would run around 100% most of the time and even with extensive googling i didn't find any relevant info, so any help would be much appreciated.

Here is all the relevant details i could think of:
GPU : Asus 1070 with ccminer reported Hash rate of +/- 580 H/s
Pool : pool.supportxmr.com:7777
Stratum difficulty: around 12000 (12.0)